# Looking for API providers for retrieving crypto transactions from various blockchains

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi

I am looking for crypto API providers/aggregators that support multiple blockchains. The API should be able to retrieve transactions given a public wallet address from any (or many) blockchain. I realize that I can deploy a miner or validator on each blockchain that would allow me to do this, but I consider this solution to be cost prohibitive.

Thanks!